# unpooling in Keras/tf

Tags: tensorflow, keras, masking

I am trying to implement unpooling for an autoencoder in VGG. Unpooling is basically tracking the history where maxpool was taken from in encoder and then applying the same in decoder. An example is shown as in the figure [we save the mask for pooling history for each maxpool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT64D.png).

Here is a simple implementation that I have done.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, UpSampling2D
import keras
from keras.layers import Lambda
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, Input
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.utils import plot_model

def unpool(args):
    mask, x = args
    #print(mask.shape, x.shape)
    return keras.layers.multiply([mask, x])

def mask_make(xt):
    t = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding = 'SAME')(xt)
    t = UpSampling2D()(t)

    bool_mask = K.greater_equal(xt, t)
    mask = K.cast(bool_mask, dtype='float32')

    #print (mask.shape)

    mask_input = Input(tensor=mask) # Makes the mask to a Keras tensor to use as input
    return mask_input

def vgg_layers(inputs, target_layer):
    # Block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(inputs)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
    m1 = mask_make(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2')(x)
    m2 = mask_make(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv4')(x)
    m3 = mask_make(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv4')(x)
    m4 = mask_make(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

    # Block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)

    # Decoder

    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block5_conv1')(x)

    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block4_conv4')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block4_conv3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block4_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block4_conv1')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2), name='decoder_block4_upsample')(x)
    x = Lambda(unpool)([m4, x])

    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block3_conv4')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block3_conv3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block3_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block3_conv1')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2), name='decoder_block3_upsample')(x)
    x = Lambda(unpool)([m3, x])

    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block2_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block2_conv1')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2), name='decoder_block2_upsample')(x)
    x = Lambda(unpool)([m2, x])

    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block1_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_block1_conv1')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2), name='decoder_block1_upsample')(x)
    x = Lambda(unpool)([m1, x])

    return x, masks

def VGG19(input_tensor=None, input_shape=(32,32,3), target_layer=1):
    """
    VGG19, up to the target layer (1 for relu1_1, 2 for relu2_1, etc.)
    """
    if input_tensor is None:
        inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    else:
        inputs = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
    layers, masks = vgg_layers(inputs, target_layer)
    model = Model(inputs, layers, name='vgg19')
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
    #load_weights(model)
    #return model, masks

VGG19()
```

However, I am getting "ValueError: Graph disconnected:"

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try debugging? Where's error occurring?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by using concatenate

```
def mask_make(x, orig):
    t = UpSampling2D()(x)
    _,a,b,c = orig.shape 
    #print (a,b,c)
    xReshaped = Reshape((1,a*b*c))(t)
    origReshaped = Reshape((1,a*b*c))(orig)
    #print (xReshaped.shape)
    #print (origReshaped.shape)
    together = Concatenate(axis = -1)([origReshaped,xReshaped])
    togReshaped = Reshape((2,a,b,c))(together)
    #print (togReshaped.shape)

    bool_mask = Lambda(lambda t: K.greater_equal(t[:,0], t[:,1]))(togReshaped)

    mask = Lambda(lambda t: K.cast(t, dtype='float32'))(bool_mask)
    #mask = Reshape((a,b,c))(mask)
    #print (mask.shape)
    return mask

def vgg_layers(inputs, target_layer):
    masks = []
    # Block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(inputs)
    if target_layer == 1:
        return x
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
    orig = x 
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)
    masks.append(mask_make(x, orig))

    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1')(x)
    if target_layer == 2:
        return x
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2')(x)
    orig = x 
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)
    masks.append(mask_make(x, orig))

    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
    if target_layer == 3:
        return x
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv4')(x)
    orig = x 
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)
    masks.append(mask_make(x, orig))

    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1')(x)
    if target_layer == 4:
        return x
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv4')(x)
    orig = x 
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)
    masks.append(mask_make(x, orig))

    # Block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)
    return x, masks


def load_weights(model):
    f = h5py.File(WEIGHTS_PATH)
    layer_names = [name for name in f.attrs['layer_names']]

    for layer in model.layers:
        b_name = layer.name.encode()
        if b_name in layer_names:
            g = f[b_name]
            weights = [g[name] for name in g.attrs['weight_names']]
            layer.set_weights(weights)
            layer.trainable = False

    f.close()


def VGG19(input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, target_layer=1):
    """
    VGG19, up to the target layer (1 for relu1_1, 2 for relu2_1, etc.)
    """
    if input_tensor is None:
        inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    else:
        inputs = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
    layers, masks = vgg_layers(inputs, target_layer)
    model = Model(inputs, layers, name='vgg19')
    load_weights(model)
    return model, masks
```